# Использование hover в ячейках таблицы.

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица из рисунков, хочу чтобы при наведении мыши на ячейку появлялся рисунок ,обводящий рисунок в ячейке. Использовала Hover. Не хочет показывать. Может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Ну Вы хотя бы напишите кусочек кода, что Вы делали.

Comment: Короче говоря: есть картинка (умывальник), при наведении курсора он обрамляется в картинку "многоугольник"

Answer (score 2):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то вот решение с использованием css:

```
<style type="text/css">
   img:hover {
    border: 2px green solid;
   }
  </style>
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2dzeS/)

С использованием javascript:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><img alt="" src="" onmouseover="this.style.border='2px green solid'" onMouseout="this.style.border='none'" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kjr/)

с использованием jquery:

```
$("td img").hover(
      function () {
          $(this).css("border","2px green solid");
      },
      function () {
           $(this).css("border","none");
      }
);
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Bjhpw/)

Comment: Короче говоря: есть картинка (умывальник), при наведении курсора он обрамляется в картинку "многоугольник".